# Inserting a while loop at oncreate method in android

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop inside my onCreate method, but it crashes all the time(without the loop works great). Can someone please help me?

This is the code:

```
            while(runnersNearby.size()<3)
{
            GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(lat, lang), radius);
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Successfully Found"+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (key != user.getUid())
                        runnersNearby.add(key);
                    Log.d("Number of users", String.valueOf(runnersNearby.size()));
                    Log.d("KEY", String.valueOf(key));
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "left the place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    runnersNearby.remove(key);
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "key moved but here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                    System.out.println("All initial data has been loaded and events have been fired!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
radius=radius*1.5;
        }
```

logcat after fixes which were recomended:

```
08-23 16:53:37.979 10116-10116/com.firebase.shahaf.datasignin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.firebase.shahaf.datasignin, PID: 10116
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.firebase.shahaf.datasignin/com.firebase.shahaf.datasignin.UserProfile}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Precision of GeoHash must be larger than zero!
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Precision of GeoHash must be larger than zero!
                                                                                    at com.firebase.geofire.core.GeoHash.<init>(GeoHash.java:29)
                                                                                    at com.firebase.geofire.core.GeoHashQuery.queriesAtLocation(GeoHashQuery.java:85)
                                                                                    at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery.setupQueries(GeoQuery.java:224)
                                                                                    at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(GeoQuery.java:325)
                                                                                    at com.firebase.shahaf.datasignin.UserProfile.onCreate(UserProfile.java:68)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Comment: Why did it crash? What exceptions are logged in the LogCat?

Comment: please add logcat stacktrace.

Comment: Query for all users, sorted by radius, take first 3 if you want to have at least 3.

Comment: also, `Precision of GeoHash must be larger than zero!` what more can be said?

Comment: @njzk2 double radius=50; not good enough?

Comment: where doe your runnersNearby get populated? Need some background here.

Comment: there is a possibility that it is a result of the infinite loop with an overflow of the double resulting in a negative radius? anyway, if you take a minute to run it in debug mode, you'll see exactly what happens.

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt i created a query which gets all the users on the geographic location around my radius, im trying to create a loop which increase the radius until it finds 3 users(which there are...), but for some reason the while loop crashes...

Comment: My actual question is: Does the while loop need to wait for some background service calling the internet to get new users? Because the UI Thread should never, ever wait for something talking to the internet. Or any network really.

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt it does...

Comment: In this case, I made a whole answer with code and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a while loop, it cant work with it, you should create another function and to call it under `onGeoQueryReady()` and over there to do the if(instead of the while), it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Infinite loop.  You're looping while(runnersNearby.size()<3).  But the size of the array never changes.  So you loop forever.  Because of that your onCreate never returns, and the system eventually kills you for taking too long to create your activity, because it assumes something is wrong.

I'm assuming what you wanted to do is loop over the runnersNearby array?

There is one place in the code where runnersNearby can change, but its in an asynchronous callback.  So it will never actually be called. until much later.

Comment: it should change since radius changes(forgot to copy that line...), as radius changes it finds more users....(works for sure...) so its not the problem...

Comment: It is the problem.  Radius changing will not change the size of your array.  You're infinitely looping, which is not allowed on the UI thread, and definitely not allowed in onCreate or other lifecycle functions.

Comment: it is , since as the radius changes , it finds more users.... (which are added to the list)

Comment: THat doesn't matter.  YOu cannot inifnitely loop in onCreate.  You cannot loop for minutes in onCreate.  You're crashing because your onCreate doesn't return fast enough.  Humor me and take out the while loop, you'll see the crash ends.

Comment: It's crashing because onCreate must return within 5 seconds or so

Comment: @GabeSechan so what solution there is to the problem? im trying to search around the my geographic area for users, theres are more then 2 nearby(i tried it without the loop), if the loop finds them it adds them to the runners list.

Comment: @secret look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Never block the UI thread with long running operations.

Comment: Asynctask is also not suitable for an infinite loop. If you need that, use a thread. My suspicion is that this is just misuse of the geoquery all around, but I'd need to look at those docs to be sure, and I don't have time this morning

Answer (score 0):

Put everything Internet/Network related in an AsyncTasks doInBackground, and add the EventListener in OnPostExecute(...). Than just start the Asynctask in onCreate and let your app wait for the EventListeners to kick in.

Edit: Quick and dirty example code:

```
public class yourClass probablyExtends Activity{
    onCreate(...){
        new LoadRunners().execute();
        NothingToSeeHereMoveAlongAndFollowYourUsualBusiness();
    }
}

public class LoadRunners extends AsyncTask {

    doInBackground(..){
        double radius = 1.0;
        while(runnersNearby.size()<3){
            loadRunners(radius);
            if(runnersNearby.size()<3)
                radius*=1.5;
        }
   }
   onPostExecute(...){
       addEventListeners();
   }
}
```